# How to catch connection errors when using Mail::SpamAssassin::Client

Tags: perl, object, spamassassin

I have trouble caughting error during create object in Perl. My part of current code is like that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Mail::SpamAssassin::Client;
use warnings;
use strict;

my $client = new Mail::SpamAssassin::Client({port => 783, host => 'localhost'});
my $message = '';

if(!$result) {
    print "Cant process a message ! Error: " . $result;
}
```

So I cant check $client variable if object has been created properly.
Only I can check only $result variable after calling the method $client->process($message)
But this is not satisfactory for me.
Example if spammassassin daemon will be offline then I got communicate in terminal:

> Failed to create connection to spamd daemon: Connection refused

Maybe can I catch this error message or error code after calling static method ?

Answer (score 2):

The module does this:

```perl
unless ($remote) {
  print "Failed to create connection to spamd daemon: $!\n";
  return;
}
```

ug. A module shouldn't do this. Worse, it writes to STDOUT instead of STDERR!

...Actually, it writes to the default file handle, which is *normally* STDOUT, but this can be changed using `select`. This presents a solution to us.

```perl
use Scope::Guard qw( guard );

sub validate {
   my ($client) = @_;
   open(my $fh, ">", $^O eq 'Win32' ? 'nul' : '/dev/null')
      or die $!;

   my $old_fh = select($fh);
   my $guard = guard { select($old_fh); };
   return $client->ping();
}

my $rv = eval { validate($client) };
die($@) if $@;
die($!) if !$rv;
```

That performs a ping request and returns and checks for the response. If you want to check creating the connection and nothing else, you can use

```perl
use Scope::Guard qw( guard );

sub validate {
   my ($client) = @_;
   open(my $fh, ">", $^O eq 'Win32' ? 'nul' : '/dev/null')
      or die $!;

   my $old_fh = select($fh);
   my $guard = guard { select($old_fh); };
   return !!$client->_create_connection();
}

validate($client)
   or die($!);
```

Note that the module creates a new connection for every method call, so it's possible a check could pass, but a later call could fail (e.g. because of a network issue).